# Android : Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm getting an error **Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it** while I retrieve some data from SQLite database table.

This is my query

```
dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(getContext());
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
                    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery("select MAX(activityObjId) from ActivityObjectList where activityId " + "= ? ", new String[]{string_ActivityId});

                    if (cursor1.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        maxACtivityObjId  = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("activityObjId"));
                        Log.e("MAX  ", "maxACtivityObjId = " + maxACtivityObjId);
                    }
                    cursor1.close();
                    db.close();
```

Comment: Please check if there is any data in table. Also check column key you are using is correct..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

you can use index in cursor1.getColumnIndex(0).

```
dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(getContext());
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
                    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery("select MAX(activityObjId) from ActivityObjectList where activityId " + "= ? ", new String[]{string_ActivityId});

                    if (cursor1.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        maxACtivityObjId  = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(0));
                        Log.e("MAX  ", "maxACtivityObjId = " + maxACtivityObjId);
                    }
                    cursor1.close();
                    db.close();
```

Comment: `getColumnIndex` a `String` parameter not `int`, your answer code cannot compile at all

Comment: @GanpatKaliya Good point. I didn't noticed this thing that query has max(activityObjId) in select clause and OP using getColumnIndex("col_name"), so +1 for cursor1.getString(0)

Answer (score 6):

Your query contains the column

```
MAX(activityObjId)
```

but you try to retrieve a column by a different name:

```
cursor1.getColumnIndex("activityObjId")
```

Therefore `getColumnIndex()` returns -1 and attempting to retrieve the value for such index causes the exception.

A solution: Retrieve with an index you've computed in your head:

```
cursor1.getString(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to try if your cursor is usable:

```
if( cursor1 != null && cursor1.moveToFirst() )
```

also in my case, this is how I use cursors successfully:

```
Cursor cursor = sql.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Comment: Still getting error of  Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.

Comment: Better to use whereArgs if needed as the OP has in their code.

Comment: if(cursor1 != null&&cursor1.getCount()){ if(cursor1.moveToFirst()) } try this one, i hope there is a problem with your query or else required table may be empty

Answer (score 1):

You should use proper `DB_Handler` class for your SQLite DB work which most developers are following now a days. I would suggest you to make a separate java class for your SQLite Database and make methods like insertion, updation, deletion to perform operations on Database

Now Come to your question. You are getting exception because your cursor is not getting desired results from query. So First check in your query column names in `select` or `where` clause should match with the column names at the time of creating table. Also confirm your `table_name` after `from` keyword in your query Then consume your query from cursor with proper checks like

```
String query = "select MAX(activityObjId) from ActivityObjectList where activityId " + string_ActivityId;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

if(c.getCount() > 0)
{
   c.moveToFirst();
   while(!c.isAfterLast())
   {
      maxACtivityObjId  = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("activityObjId"));
      Log.e("MAX  ", "maxACtivityObjId = " + maxACtivityObjId);// here you should check your column name and match (spellings) with column names at the time of creating table
      c.moveToNext();
   }
   c.close();
}
```

Further you should follow a proper tutorial for handling SQLite Database in Android Application. [Use This Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

**EDIT**

According to @Ganpat Kaliya Answer. I didn't noticed the point. The OP using `MAX(col_name)` in `select` clause and using `c.getColumnIndex('col_name')` so `c.getString(0)` did the trick according to the OP's current query.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access this column `activityObjId`, which is NOT PPRESENT in your cursor (you only have `Max(activityObjId)`).
You can use an ALIAS for that column and then access that alias:

```
Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT Max(activityObjId) AS MaxValue FROM ActivityObjectList WHERE activityId " + "= ? ", new String[]{string_ActivityId});
```

and then access it so

```
maxACtivityObjId  = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("MaxValue"));
```